# TextField TextController not working inside Stateful widget

Tags: flutter

I have created a Stateful widget to show my Alert Dialog which contains a searchbar , however the search bar text doesn't update on typing and stays blank. I have set the controller of the textfield as TextEditingController() however its still not working.

code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_convertor/Data Models/Society.dart';

class MyDialogContent extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _MyDialogContentState createState() => new _MyDialogContentState();
}

class _MyDialogContentState extends State<MyDialogContent> {

  @override
  void initState(){

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    //Search bar

    Container searchBar = Container(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0, right: 0.0),
        child: TextField(
          onChanged: (value) {
            filterSearchResults(value);
          },
          controller: TextEditingController(),
          decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: "Search",
              prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15.0)))),
        ),
      ),
    );


    AlertDialog dialog = AlertDialog(
      title: searchBar,
      content: Container(
   ....
      ),
    );



    return dialog;
  }
}
```

The controller works in my main dart file. but not when i put in my Alert Dialog stateful Widget

Comment: dialogs has their own states to update them either you can use scoped model or create new stateful class and put your alertdialog there then call alert dialog from there

Comment: I know they have their own states, which is why i created a Stateful class for my Alert Dialog

Answer (score 0):

this one is the same way that you use, this will not work

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

class Sample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SampleState createState() => new _SampleState();
}

class _SampleState extends State<Sample> {
  List<String> countries = <String>['Belgium','France','Italy','Germany','Spain','Portugal'];
  int _selectedCountryIndex = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_){_showDialog();});
  }

  _buildList(){
    if (countries.length == 0){
      return new Container();
    }

    return new Column(
      children: new List<RadioListTile<int>>.generate(
        countries.length,
        (int index){
          return new RadioListTile<int>(
            value: index,
            groupValue: _selectedCountryIndex,
            title: new Text(countries[index]),
            onChanged: (int value) {
              setState((){
                _selectedCountryIndex = value;
              });
            },
          );
        }
      )
    );
  }

  _showDialog() async{
    await showDialog<String>(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context){
        return new CupertinoAlertDialog(
          title: new Text('Please select'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            new CupertinoDialogAction(
              isDestructiveAction: true,
              onPressed: (){Navigator.of(context).pop('Cancel');},
              child: new Text('Cancel'),
            ),
            new CupertinoDialogAction(
              isDestructiveAction: true,
              onPressed: (){Navigator.of(context).pop('Accept');},
              child: new Text('Accept'),
            ),
          ],
          content: new SingleChildScrollView(
            child: new Material(
              child: _buildList(),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
      barrierDismissible: false,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container();
  }
}
```

you should do it like below

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

class Sample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SampleState createState() => new _SampleState();
}

class _SampleState extends State<Sample> {
  List<String> countries = <String>['Belgium','France','Italy','Germany','Spain','Portugal'];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_){_showDialog();});
  }

  _showDialog() async{
    await showDialog<String>(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context){
        return new CupertinoAlertDialog(
          title: new Text('Please select'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            new CupertinoDialogAction(
              isDestructiveAction: true,
              onPressed: (){Navigator.of(context).pop('Cancel');},
              child: new Text('Cancel'),
            ),
            new CupertinoDialogAction(
              isDestructiveAction: true,
              onPressed: (){Navigator.of(context).pop('Accept');},
              child: new Text('Accept'),
            ),
          ],
          content: new SingleChildScrollView(
            child: new Material(
              child: new MyDialogContent(countries: countries),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
      barrierDismissible: false,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container();
  }
}

class MyDialogContent extends StatefulWidget {
  MyDialogContent({
    Key key,
    this.countries,
  }): super(key: key);

  final List<String> countries;

  @override
  _MyDialogContentState createState() => new _MyDialogContentState();
}

class _MyDialogContentState extends State<MyDialogContent> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
  }

  _getContent(){
    if (widget.countries.length == 0){
      return new Container();
    }

    return new Column(
      children: new List<RadioListTile<int>>.generate(
        widget.countries.length,
        (int index){
          return new RadioListTile<int>(
            value: index,
            groupValue: _selectedIndex,
            title: new Text(widget.countries[index]),
            onChanged: (int value) {
              setState((){
                _selectedIndex = value;
              });
            },
          );
        }
      )
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _getContent();
  }
}
```